# How to resize a div on drag? [Issue with rotation]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to be able to re-size a div when dragging two handlers.

Please use the following link

http://jsbin.com/lopumaheyu/1/

Click the green box, after drag orange boxes, the script work correctly and green box is re-sized.

I have an issue when CSS rotation is being applied to the green box, example:

http://output.jsbin.com/zirugeroju/1/

As you can notice there is a swift for the opposite knob an user is dragging.

- What could be wrong here and how to fix it?
- A better solution also with jQuery is also welcome

---

```
 resize: function (handler, event) {
                if (event.clientX <= 0) { // cover bug
                    return;
                }
                var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.elm);
                switch (handler) {
                    case 'tl':
                        // x
                        var marginR = elm.offsetLeft + elm.clientWidth,
                            newW = marginR - event.clientX,
                            xPos = event.clientX;
                        elm.style.left = xPos + 'px';
                        elm.style.width = newW + 'px';
                        // y
                        var marginT = elm.offsetTop + elm.clientHeight,
                            newH = marginT - event.clientY,
                            yPos = event.clientY;

                        elm.style.top = yPos + 'px';
                        elm.style.height = newH + 'px';
                        this.setPositionHandlers();
                        break;
                    case 'tr':
                        break;
                    case 'bl':
                        break;
                    case 'br':
                        var newW = event.clientX - this.config.x,
                            newH = event.clientY - this.config.y;
                        elm.style.width = newW + 'px';
                        elm.style.height = newH + 'px';
                        this.setPositionHandlers();
                        break;
                }
            },
```

Comment: The div is not draggable... I really don't see any difference with the two links, they both seem to work fine. I recommend setting minimum height though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please try to first click the green div, you will see to orange div that can be dragged.

Comment: The orange ones are called handles, in any case, they both work fine, what's the problem?

Comment: @odedta please try to use the following link http://output.jsbin.com/zirugeroju/1/ when you drag the orange bottom right handler, you can see the position of the top left orange handler switfing a little.... I need to avoid the swifting

Comment: example when you drag RIGHT, TOP LEFT handler move slightly on TOP

Comment: I see, I think that happens because you're using `transform: rotate(10deg);`, basically everytime you resize the box, the rotation is being calculated again. Let me think.

Comment: Damn @Gibbok, that is a very good question man, I think you need to compensate for the movement, what I mean is: know how much the box is moving in relation to how much the box width and height changed, then you can move it the opposite direction if the box dimensions are changed and by that you can eliminate this silly thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: left top;
```

on `#target` to avoid the little swift on top left orange handler.

```
#target {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```